# using Kinesis Client library with Spark Steaming PySpark

Tags: python-2.7, spark-streaming, amazon-kcl

I am looking for using KCL on SparkStreaming using pySpark.
Any pointers would be helpful.

I tried few given by spark Kinesis Ingeration link.

But i get the error for JAVA class reference.

Seems Python is using JAVA class.

i tried linking
spark-streaming-kinesis-asl-assembly_2.10-2.0.0-preview.jar
while trying to apply the KCL app on spark.

but still having the error.

Please let me know if anyone has done it already.

if i search online i get more about Twitter and Kafka.
Not able to get much help with regard to Kinesis.

spark verision used: 1.6.3

Comment: i tried with spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.10-1.6.3.jar     the error i got is ...Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.InitialPositionInStream

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. The kinesis-asl jar had several files missing.

To overcome this problem, I had included the following jars in my spark-submit.

1. amazon-kinesis-client-1.9.0.jar
2. aws-java-sdk-1.11.310.jar
3. jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.6.7.jar

Note: I am using Spark 2.3.0 so the jar versions listed might not be the same as those you should be using for your spark version.

Hope this helps.